# trim unused outer parts of the axis in vega-lite v3

Tags: vega-lite

How can I "trim" the axis and get rid of that padding on both sides beyond `[-101, 225]` ***specifically in Vega-Lite v3*** ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scale.domain` along with `scale.nice=false`. This works both in Vega-Lite v3 and v4. For example:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.4.0.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"label": "A", "value": -101},
      {"label": "B", "value": -50},
      {"label": "C", "value": 10},
      {"label": "D", "value": 116},
      {"label": "E", "value": 225}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"field": "label", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {
      "field": "value",
      "scale": {"domain": [-101, 225], "nice": false},
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {"field": "label", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image]